# PHP String array to Javascript object array with AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

My PHP Script is returning the following string through an AJAX call in javascript:

```
$maaltijdPrijzenArray = "[";
...while...
    $maaltijdPrijzenArray .= "{id: $id, maaltijdprijs: \"$kostprijs\", verkoopprijs: \"$verkoopprijs\"},";
...endwhile...
$maaltijdPrijzenArray = rtrim($maaltijdPrijzenArray, ',');
$maaltijdPrijzenArray .= "]";
$response['arrayMaaltijden'] = $maaltijdPrijzenArray;

echo json_encode($response);
```

so an example output is :

```
$maaltijdPrijzenArray = "[ 
    {id: 1, maaltijdprijs: "23.23", verkoopprijs: "44.34" },
    {id: 2, maaltijdprijs: "34.34", verkoopprijs: "55.55"} ]";
```

I send this output to my AJAX call in Javascript (My ajax call has dataType: 'JSON' enabled), where I want my array to be in the same format but now in Javascript. So desired output must be in javascript:

```
var maaltijdPrijzenArray = [ 
        {id: 1, maaltijdprijs: "23.23", verkoopprijs: "44.34" }
        {id: 2, maaltijdprijs: "34.34", verkoopprijs: "55.55"} ]
```

From this I can simply get "maaltijdprijs" and "verkoopprijs" by calling

```
var result = $.grep(maaltijdPrijzen, function(e){ return e.id == id; });
```

But how do I convert the PHP array to Javascript?

Comment: Have you tried to `JSON.parse()` the string?

Comment: In the output, you are missing a `,` after the first object. Is that a typo? Else, it's one problem.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Thanks, yes I forgot it.

Comment: Chris Riebschlager is correct: your PHP service is returning a string which you need to parse back into an array of objects using JSON.parse(), on the JS side. Also, make sure all your object properties are declared as strings: `"property": "value"` instead of `property:"value"`.

Comment: @ChrisRiebschlager If I use JSON.parse() I get the following error referring to the "i" of "id": Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 2

Comment: side note - don't manually build a javascript array in php. build a php array, and then `json_encode()` the php array, to prevent errors.

Comment: @Sean Would like to learn how to do that. It must be in the Javascript output. You know how to build a PHP array like that? : [ {id: 1, stuff: "sef"}, {id: 2, stuff: "sef3"}] how to build this in PHP?

Comment: Then I'd follow What @Sean mentioned above. In JSON, your keys need to be in quotes. `json_encode()` will ensure this happens if you run it on a PHP array.

Comment: @ChrisRiebschlager Yes, that would be the best option. You know how to write the Javascript array as a PHP array so I can later convert it back to Javascript?

Comment: Right now, you're json_encoding a string and not an array. JS doesn't like to get json strings. It wants json to be either an object or an array. You get the error because after JSON.parse(), you will still just have a string (you've basically double encoded the json). If you would remove the `json_encode()` and just do `echo $response;`, it should work (if the string is valid json, that is).

Comment: Instead of concatenating a string -> `$maaltijdPrijzenArray .= "{id: $id,...`, do it as a php array -> `$maaltijdPrijzenArray = array(); ...while... $maaltijdPrijzenArray[] = array("id"=>$id,...`. This would also get rid of the need for `rtrim()`.

Comment: @Sean This worked! Thanks for the help everyone

Answer (score 0):

Credits: @Sean

Instead of concatenating a string -> `$maaltijdPrijzenArray .= "{id: $id,...`, do it as a php array -> `$maaltijdPrijzenArray = array(); ...while... $maaltijdPrijzenArray[] = array("id"=>$id,....` This would also get rid of the need for rtrim()

Changed my PHP to:

```
$maaltijdPrijzenArray = array();
$maaltijdPrijzenArray[] = array("id"=>$id, "maaltijdprijs"=>$kostprijs, "verkoopprijs"=>$verkoopprijs);
$response['arrayMaaltijden'] = $maaltijdPrijzenArray;
echo json_encode($response);
```

And it worked in Javascript :)

Answer (score 0):

echo the PHP array as a JSON string with the `[json_encode][1]` function.

Then when you read out this String in JavaScipt, you can turn it into an array with the `[JSON.parse][2]` function.

1: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
2: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp